# How can I listen to MDC search bar typed-in String, in order to display results onto SearchView UI?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, material-design, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I've tried to connect the Material Design Component Search Bar component into my Android Studio, but I have difficulties doing so.

- Firstly, I'm not sure whether `searchView.getEditText().setOnEditorActionListener` let me listen to the current typed string in the search Bar.
- Secondly, I want to know how I can correctly display the list of results I put in a HashMap called `` `searchResults `` within the method `` `updateSearchResultUI ``  .If the implementation is wrong, please correct me.

onCreateView method in my fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_page, container, false);


    //INSTANTIATE FIRESTORE
    Firestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


    //SEARCH BAR DECLARATION
    searchBar=(SearchBar) view.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
    searchView=(SearchView)view.findViewById(R.id.search_view);

    searchView.getEditText().setOnEditorActionListener(
            (v, actionId, event) -> {
                searchBar.setText(searchView.getText());
                searchView.getEditText().addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                        String searchText = editable.toString();
                        performSearch(searchText, view);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });







    return view;
}
```

performSearch() method to search string currently typed in searchbar inside Firestore

```
private void performSearch(String searchText, View view) {
    CollectionReference usersRef = Firestore.collection("Users");

    Query query = usersRef.whereEqualTo("username", searchText);

    query.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            List<Map<String, Object>> searchResults = new ArrayList<>();  // Directly work with Map

            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Map<String, Object> userData = document.getData();
                searchResults.add(userData);
            }

            updateSearchResultUI(searchResults, view);

            // Update your UI with searchResults
        } else {
            // Handle errors
            Log.e(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    });
}
```

updateSearchResultUI() to update the list of results from Firestore onto a List, then to update in SearchView UI

```
public void updateSearchResultUI(List<Map<String, Object>> searchResults, View view) {
    ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    // Create a list of strings to store the usernames
    List<String> usernames = new ArrayList<>();

    // Iterate through each search result map
    for (Map<String, Object> result : searchResults) {
        // Assuming "username" is the key for the username in the map
        String username = (String) result.get("username");

        // Add the username to the list
        if (username != null) {
            usernames.add(username);
        }
    }

    // Create an ArrayAdapter to bind the data to the ListView
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(view.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, usernames);

    // Set the adapter to the ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I'm new in using Android Material Components, and I wish that I could get any help on how I can display my Firestore results seamlessly onto my UI. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo sorry, what I meant to ask is how can I listen to the typed string onto search bar. Seems like my ```searchView.getEditText().addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()``` is not working

Comment: "is not working" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?